# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class

Tags: java, class

Consider the following Java class structure:

```java
public class myClass {
  class myInnerClass {}
}
```

After compiling with the command `javac myClass.java`, two class files are generated: `myClass.class` and `myClass$myInnerClass.class`.

i got 2 files: `myClass.class` and `myClass$myInnerClass.class`

In a separate `Main.java` file, I am using `URLClassLoader` to dynamically load `myClass.class` and execute a method from it that involves the usage of the `myInnerClass`. However, I encountered the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class myClass$myInnerClass from class myClass (myClass$myInnerClass is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; myClass is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @41cf53f9)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

I attempted to modify the `classpath` or `module path` when using `URLClassLoader` to ensure proper module accessibility.

I expected the dynamically loaded `myClass` to successfully access and utilize `myInnerClass` without encountering the `IllegalAccessError`. However, the issue persists despite my attempts.

Comment: Can you make a complete working example. Eg. Class your building and the class you're trying to dynamically load the other class with. How does you code know where to find the innerclass? It won't use the source file, so it needs to access the actuall generated class file.

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample, myInnerClass is a non-static inner class of myClass. You need to instantiate it the following way:

```
myClass outerObject = new myClass();
myClass.myInnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new myInnerClass();
```

You are getting `java.lang.IllegalAccessError` because you are accessing your non-static inner class from a context that does not allow so. You can also make the inner class static and try if myInnerClass does not rely on the state of myClass.

Read the access rules of the nested classes [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: You sure? The error message suggests its more a thing of one module failing to export this to another one - Java17+ breaks reflection rather thoroughly - private stuff is now private and reflection cannot access it any more.

Comment: I access it using URLClassLoader, not the class. `URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{urlToClassFile}); Class<?> myClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("myClass"); Method method = myClass.getMethod("myMethod"); method.invoke();` Suppose there is a myMethod in myClass and when run it activates class or new class and leads to the error I mentioned.

Comment: @HuyWallz This is the type of thing you should edit your question and add the information. If you make a complete example, somebody can find what you're doing wrong, or confirm that it is broken. As it stands, how is java going to find your myClass$innerClass.class?